# What causes this ArchUnit exception?

Tags: java, archunit

Thanks for your time,

I've been experimenting with Archunit, and I can't get my head around this issue:

```
ComponentIntersectionException: Class 
com.yyy.xxx.common.configurations.properties.SomeClass may not be contained in more 
than one component, but is contained in [Common, Configuration]
```

I have a fairly standard plantuml diagram; And although I'd rather not share it, there may be some nuance of ArchUnit, that I'm missing. My question is what, specifically, at a high level must I be doing incorrectly?

Additional info:
test:

```
    @Test
    void diagram_layersShouldBeRespected() throws IOException {
        classes().should(adhereToPlantUmlDiagram(PLANTUML_YAMl, consideringOnlyDependenciesInDiagram())).check(ALL_PROJECT_CLASSES);
    }
```

yaml:

```
@startuml
 
package "Config" {
  [Configuration] <<..configurations.properties..>>
//this is where SomeClass resides
}
 
package "Web Layer" {
  [Controller] <<..web.controllers..>>
  [Resources] <<..web.resources..>>
}
 
package "Business Layer" {
  [Services] <<..services..>>
  [Business Model] <<..models..>>
}
 
package "Adapter Layer" {
  [Databases] <<..dataaccess..>>
  [Integration] <<..adapters.azure..>> 
  [Storage] <<..adapters.azure.storage..>> 
}
 
package "Common Layer" {
  [Common] <<..common..>>
}
 
[Configuration] --> [Services]
[Configuration] --> [Storage]
[Configuration] --> [Common]
[Configuration] --> [Configuration]
[Common] --> [Configuration]
 
[Controller] --> [Resources]
[Controller] --> [Services]
[Controller] --> [Common]
[Resources] --> [Common]
 
[Services] --> [Databases]
[Services] --> [Integration]
[Services] --> [Storage]
[Services] --> [Common]
 
[Databases] --> [Common]
[Integration] --> [Common]
[Storage] --> [Common]
 
@enduml
```

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of `SomeClass` in your code or modules, i.e. are `Common` and `Configuration` modules or libraries that each contain this class?

Comment: Thanks, no, I can confirm this is not the case.

Comment: You might then need to share some more details, e.g. what are `Common` and `Configuration`, how are they related to `SomeClass` etc.

Comment: I have added additional info now

Comment: I'm not familiar with ArchUnit but given the yaml you've provided: could it be that the package `...common.configurations.properties...` would be assigned to 2 components by ArchUnit? So `<<..common..>>` would match "Common Layer" while `<<..configurations.properties..>>` would match "Config".

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll look into it. But where is this limit stipulated?".SomeClass may not be contained in more than one component"

Comment: This probably is defined in some basic rules since your application should not contain the same class in multiple modules or you'd run into nasty bugs and conflicts. I assume that ArchUnit checks packages and assumes the class could be put into 2 modules due to the mapping in the YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Thomas got me thinking in the region of the source of my problem, I have solved it, as follows:

The problem was that the packages that were part of my description of a component(A) were too vague, such that a description of another component(B), could also be considered of that component(A), so some of my classes were thought to belong to >=2 components.